# Why retain count of self increases inside block?

Tags: objective-c-blocks

```
__block typeof(self) selfPointer = self;

[StudentClass callComputerScienceStudent:dept
    completionBlock:^(Department *dept) {
        [selfPointer getEntry:dept];
    }
    errorBlock:^(Department *dept) {
        [selfPointer deleteEntry:dept];
    }];
```

Here self has retain count of 2. and selfPointer is readonly. 
What changes are required to make selfPointer read-write instead of readonly.

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Answer (score 1):

Blocks capture variables used in their context. If you want to avoid capturing a strong reference, you may do the following:
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

```
[StudentClass 
    callComputerScienceStudent:dept 
    completionBlock:^(Department *dept) { 
        [weakSelf getEntry:dept];
    } 
    errorBlock:^(Department *dept) {
        [weakSelf deleteEntry:dept];
    }];
```

This ensures that only a weak reference of `self` is used within the block.

Additionally, as @mttrb pointed out in a comment, using `retainCount` is absolutely unreliable. In order to avoid memory issues with blocks, I suggest you read this [great article](https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/).

Comment: Using the `__block` modifier will take care of that.

Comment: No...Compiler gives error warning.. that  Read-only variable is not assignable

Comment: Can you post your `deleteEntry` method? If there are other variables there, they also need the `__block` modifier.